# How to "Quote" a String in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, quotes

**Info's:** I have some javascript code that i will show below, who i'm having problem with quotes.

```js
html = [];
style = 'class=odd';
html.push('<li '+style+' onclick=SelectItem("'+ele.id+'","'+idItem+'","'+dsItem+'","'+qtItem+'"); >'+id+' - '+$iObjItensListaVenda.result.ds_item[i]+'</li>');
```

I have strings that i get from a JSON Object, as you see above.

**Problem:** But when i'm trying to place it as a Function Parameter on the `onClick` event of the `<li>` element, my resulting html `<li>` element becomes totally unformatted like that:

```html
<li natural,"150");="" white="" american="" onclick="SelectItem("descItem1","2",TELHA" class="odd">00002 - TELHA AMERICAN WHITE NATURAL</li>
```

**What do i want:** i need a solution like a function, maybe already exists in jQuery, to Quote my String. Like a `QuoteStr("s t r i n g");` to become `""s t r i n g""`.

**Maybe you're complaining about:**

1. The variable `ele` is a html `<input>` element.
2. The variable `idItem` contains only numbers, they come from a JSON Object.
3. The variable `dsItem` its a string containing Item Description, it comes from the JSON Object too.
4. The variable `qtItem` contains only numbers, it is the quantity of the items, it comes from the JSON too.

Comment: onclick = 'SelectItem("desc...","we..")';

Comment: Here's a thorough answer that deals with escaping quotes: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9756789/470480

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I escape quotes in HTML attribute values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7753448/how-do-i-escape-quotes-in-html-attribute-values)

Comment: The sane solution would be to use jQuery to bind the event handler, not building an HTML string.

Comment: @FelixKling this will be problematic because i have dinamic parameters and if im thinking about bind one each one, there is a problem because my `<li>` do not have any identifier.

Comment: These are  no problems. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The sane solution would be to use [jQuery to build the element](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery-html-attributes) and bind the event handler, not building an HTML string:

```
var $li = $('<li />', {
    "class": "odd",
    on: {
       click: function() {
           SelectItem(ele.id, idItem, dsItem, qtItem);
       }
    },
    text: id + ' - ' + $iObjItensListaVenda.result.ds_item[i]
});
```

If you are doing this in a loop and the variables end up having the wrong values, please see [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example). Alternative you could use jQuery's [`.data` API](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to set and get those values.

Comment: How i can implement this method when i need to append a lot of `<li>`'s to my desired `<ul>`? at the moment i'm using a array to store all the `<li>` inside a loop and then using `document.getElementById('my_div').innerHTML = array.join('');` to put it inside the ul.

Comment: appending one by one inside the loop? this is not slow?

Comment: You can also append all of them at once after the loop. `.append` accepts an array of DOM elements. Or you can add each of the `li` elements to a jQuery object and just append that one.

Comment: how? because i do have only one `$li` variable that stores one custom `<li>`

Comment: `var $lis = []; ... $lis.push($li.get(0)); ... $('#ulid').append($lis);` or `var $lis = $(); ... $lis.add($li); ... $('#ulid').append($lis);`. I assume you knew how to add values to an array because you are already doing this in your original code.

Comment: it not worked, i got: `<li class="odd" on="[object Object]">00002 - TELHA AMERICAN WHITE NATURAL</li>`

Comment: Which jQuery version are you using?

Comment: Ah, I think jQuery `1.7.1` doesn't have `.on` yet. Then remove `on:` and move the `click:` property one level up, i.e. `{"class": ..., click: ...., text: ....}`.

Comment: still do not worked, but i have found the problem, it is `onclick:` and not `click:` and i still have to escape with quotes but now it worked, this is the result that works, edit your answer please :) `var $li = $('<li />', {
                  "class": style,
                  onclick: "SelectItem(\""+ele.id+"\","+idItem+",\""+dsItem+"\","+qtItem+")",
                  text: id + ' - ' + $iObjItensListaVenda.result.ds_item[i]
              });`

Comment: But that's exactly what you shouldn't do, because it's not better than building the HTML string. If this really doesn't work (whatever you mean by that) then bind the handler after you created the element: `var $li = $('<li />', {...}).click(function() {...});`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45699/discussion-between-paulo-roberto-and-felix-kling)

Answer (score 0):

Try `\"` instead of `'` in `onClick`

```
$(".container").append("<a href='javascript:void(0)' onClick=\"showField('"+data.name+"','"+data.text+"');\">Edit</a>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always use backslash to escape quotes:

```
console.log('te\'st'); // te'st
console.log("te\"st"); // te"st
```

You can do the same thing for your string, but I'd suggest you rewrite the whole thing into something more usable. By that I mean not using strings to build objects, but building objects directly.

For example:

```
var li = document.createElement('li');
li.className = myClass;
li.onclick = function(){/*...*/};
```

It gets even easier with jQuery.

Comment: Note that won't work for quotes inside attribute values.

Comment: @KevinB Attributes seem wrong even when they first come from JSON... However, my answer was about fixing the onclick part... there's a lot of mess. But I'd really rewrite the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use quotes in a string by escaping them with a backslash.

```
var text = "s t r i n g";
"\"" + text + "\"" === "\"s t r i n g\"";
```

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String