# single quotes breaking down the JavaScript String

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I put Single quote in text box, it does not show in dynamically added textbox. See following example :

```
$("#abc").before("<div><input type='text' value='" + $scope.txt + "'/></div>");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/15777/

Comment: Of you include a single quote in your string it breaks the string you're inserting with jQuery.

Comment: Use `escape`: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/U3pVM/15778/

Comment: But it is showing %27 with the value

Comment: @user3806762 Check http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/15779/

Comment: @ketan that breaks double quotes

Comment: @ketan Now it is not showing Double quotes

Comment: Not to be "that guy", but using jQuery for DOM manipulation inside Angular is a really bad idea. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background/15012542#15012542

Answer (score 4):

I've had a similar problem some time ago, and found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/9756789/2619170

See the quoteattr function, that's what you need: http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/15780/

```
function quoteattr(s, preserveCR) {
    preserveCR = preserveCR ? '&#13;' : '\n';
    return ('' + s) /* Forces the conversion to string. */
        .replace(/&/g, '&amp;') /* This MUST be the 1st replacement. */
        .replace(/'/g, '&apos;') /* The 4 other predefined entities, required. */
        .replace(/"/g, '&quot;')
        .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
        .replace(/>/g, '&gt;')
        /*
        You may add other replacements here for HTML only 
        (but it's not necessary).
        Or for XML, only if the named entities are defined in its DTD.
        */ 
        .replace(/\r\n/g, preserveCR) /* Must be before the next replacement. */
        .replace(/[\r\n]/g, preserveCR);
        ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I have assumed that you want "text with quote" as an input to be added and displayed without quotes.

```
 function TodoCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.txt = "";
    $scope.addBefore = function() {
        $("#abc").before("<div><input type=\"text\" value=" + $scope.txt + "></div>");
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `_'_` by `<code>&ampapos;<code>` , or `_"_` by `<code>&ampquot;<code>`

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/15786/)

```
    function TodoCtrl($scope) {
     $scope.txt = "";
     $scope.addBefore = function() {
        $("#abc").before("<div><input type='text' value='" + $scope.txt.replace("'","&apos;") + "'/></div>");
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.txt = "";
    $scope.addBefore = function() {
        $("#abc").before('<div><input type="text" value="' + $scope.txt + '"></div>');
    };
}
```

just change from double to single

http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/15784/

Answer (score 0):

I have done this by replacing the single or double Quote by equivalent HTML code.