# Passing a value to a function on onclick from various "identical" buttons

Tags: javascript, parameter-passing

I am using this code to generate HTML showing a table of various members taken from a database, each having their own edit a delete button. I want each row to have a unique id that is equals to an id that each member has.

```
function showMembers(member){
       member.forEach(function(x){  
         let table = document.getElementById("memberTable")
         let rowCount = table.rows.lenght;
         let row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
         row.id=x.memberId
         let cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
         let cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
         let cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
         let cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
         row.insertCell(4).innerHTML = '<button type="button"> Edit </button>'
         row.insertCell(5).innerHTML = '<button type="button" id="deleteButton" onclick ="deleteMember(this)"> Delete </button>'
         document.getElementById("deleteButton").value=row.id
         cell2.innerHTML = x.lastname;
         cell3.innerHTML = x.address;
         cell4.innerHTML = x.phone;

      });}
```

When i click the delete button it will call this function that is located on a different javascript file

```
 function deleteMember(Id) {
            let url = config.servicesPath + "/member"
            const ajax = new AJAXConnection(url)
            ajax.onsuccess = viewMessage
            ajax.del([Id])
          }
```

How can i correctly pass the uique Id from each button over to the deleteMember function?

Comment: Can I use jQuery?

Comment: You cannot have multiple buttons with the same id `deleteButton` in a document. Better don't use `innerHTML` and create the button properly.

Comment: You have a typo in the line `let rowCount = table.rows.lenght;` - it should be `length`, not `lenght`

Comment: No you cant use JQuery. Its for a school assignment and we can only use normal javascript.

Comment: And thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 0):

The simplest mode in you case would be to generate the `onclick` handler using the `row.id` directly:

```
row.insertCell(5).innerHTML = '<button type="button" id="deleteButton" onclick="deleteMember(' + row.id + ')"> Delete </button>'
```

Note: the above is a simple example that assumes `row.id` is numeric, else you will want to escape/serialize its value: [How do I escape quotes in HTML attribute values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7753448/how-do-i-escape-quotes-in-html-attribute-values)

Comment: That only works if `row.id` serialises to proper html and javascript.

Comment: @Bergi `row.id` seems to be an integer, so I see no problem there.

Comment: If it comes to this, it would be reasonable to generate unique IDs for each button as well:
id="deleteButton-' + row.id + '"

document.getElementById("deleteButton") might fail in case of 2+ buttons.

Comment: @ZoliSzabo Seems to? I don't see anything indicating that. Yes, for numbers it usually works, but it's still sloppy (and breaks as soon as the format of ids changes).

Comment: The Id will always be a number so I dont think I have to worry about the format changing. And this is pretty much my first time using javascript so I can imagine there are better ways to do this that I dont know about

Comment: @Bergi I understood your concern and updated my answer accordingly.
It seems that my answer helped the user, and I really doubt that the ID in this case will ever be altered to some format that would break this code.

Comment: Thanks, though just escaping it in the first place would be better than a warning :-) Btw, a space between attribute name and equal sign is nothing but a stylistic issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'd give the buttons a data attribute containing the row id and set the click handler to use that.

That would make the html look something like this:

```
<button onclick="deleteMember(this.getAttribute('data-rowid'))" class="delete-button" data-rowid="theid">delete</button>
```