# How escape multiple quotes in a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, escaping, quotes, double-quotes

```
var mystring1= "'Create new folder' not working (Registry Fix)";
var mystring2 = ""Create new folder" not working (Registry Fix)";
var str = "<div itemname="+mystring1+" title ="+mystring2+">";
```

But when i'm inspecting the element after this html is rendered i see

```
"div itemname "Create new folder" not working (Registry Fix) title "Create new folder" not working (Registry Fix)>
```

But i want in this format

```
<div itemname='Create new folder' not working (Registry Fix) title="Create new folder" not working (Registry Fix)>
```

I want a general escape sequence method to use for both single quotes and double quotes.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Escape_notation and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7753448/how-do-i-escape-quotes-in-html-attribute-values

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: You should be getting a syntax error on the `var mystring2` line.

Comment: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: What you want doesn't seem to be right, either. Everything after `Create new folder` isn't part of the attributes.

Comment: 'Create new folder' not working (Registry Fix)
This is the entire string i want

Comment: @Sanjay use template literals

Comment: @Sanjay Then it should be `itemname="'Create new folder' not working (Registry Fix)"`

Comment: And `title='"Create new folder" not working (Registry Fix)'`

Comment: The code you posted can't be what you're actually running, since it has a syntax error. And if you fix the syntax error, it won't produce the actual results that you show.

Comment: @Tibebes.M That doesn't solve the problem of the quoting in the attributes, just quoting of the string literals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is to not use string operations to create DOM elements, use DOM methods.

```js
var mystring1 = "'Create new folder' not working (Registry Fix)";
var mystring2 = '"Create new folder" not working (Registry Fix)';
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.setAttribute("itemname", mystring1);
div.setAttribute("title", mystring2);
div.innerText = "hover or click on me";
div.addEventListener("click", function() {
  console.log(this.getAttribute("itemname"));
}); document.getElementById("container").appendChild(div);
```

```html
<div id="container">
</div>
```

Comment: If i want to create inputs and span classes inside that DOM how do i achieve it using DOM methods?

Comment: The same way, with `document.createElement` and `div.appendChild`

Answer (score -1):

Use escape character \ where you need to escape string literals.

`var mystring1 = "'Create new folder' not working (Registry Fix)";`

`var mystring2 = "\"Create new folder\" not working (Registry Fix)";`

`var str = "<div itemname = \"" + mystring1 + "\" title = '" + mystring2 + "'>Something</div>";`

Comment: This won't work correctly, you need quotes around the attributes. And the quotes can't match the quotes that are in the attributes.

Comment: I wrote the answer to get the output what you've posted. This answer will give you the output for expected format. which is - <div itemname='Create new folder' not working (Registry Fix) title="Create new folder" not working (Registry Fix)>

Comment: He's obviously not quoting it correctly in the HTML he wants, either.

Comment: This is the same as what he wrote, except you fixed the syntax error in the string literal. But that's obviously not what he's actually running because it can't run at all.

Comment: Note here that in my answer I purposely removed close </div> element. So until you put the closing tag, the div is incomplete. So it should be like this var str = "<div itemname = " + mystring1 + " title = " + mystring2 + "></div>";

Comment: Yes, absolutely correct. So using the setAttribute method he can dynamically add attributes to div element.

Comment: There's no `</div>` in the question.

Comment: Yes Barmar, that's why I didn't include it. I edited the answer a little bit. It should work now. But your answer is the better and perfect fit for this problem. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Thank you for the solutions, I tried with DOM methods as @Barmar said. Now its working file for me. And sorry I forgot to close div tag in question.