# How to pass string in Javascript function dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a javascript function like this

```
function doIt(link) {
    alert(link);
}
```

And i call this function in below given JS code, where i am creating an a tag and appending it to my html page on runtime:

```
jQuery.each(data, function (i, val) {
    var card = '<a href="Views/NewsDetail.html" onclick=" doIt(' + val.Img + '); "> \
                <div class=" card"> \
                <img src='+ val.Img + ' /> \
                <p>'+ val.Title + '</p> \
                </div> \
                </a>';
    document.getElementById('News').innerHTML += card;
});
```

Say for example our `val.Img = 'abcd'`
When i click the a tag it calls `doIt(abcd)`, but i want to call `doIt('abcd')` passing it as string.

Is there any workaround for this.

Comment: Doesn't it redirect to another page `Views/NewsDetail.html` when you click anchor tag?

Comment: Thanx everyone for helping me. though i can only accept one answer but giving +1 for helping me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape quotes like

```
var card ='<a href="Views/NewsDetail.html" onclick="doIt(\'' + val.Img + '\'); "> \
                                                        //^               ^
```

As per your current implementation the argument `abcd` is treated as variable thus you must be getting `undefined`

Comment: lemme try this and get back to you.

Comment: Yeah exactly it is giving me undefined.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this one:

```
var card='<a href="Views/NewsDetail.html;" onClick="Test(\'' + val.Img + '\'); "></a>';
```

Answer (score 1):

The below HTML string already used both quotes till the characters `doIt(`. So any string type values inside the quotes, must be escaped using any of the quote-character.

```
 var card = '<a href="Views/NewsDetail.html" onclick=" doIt(' + val.Img + '); ">'
```

to [added quote escape character \"]

```
 var card = '<a href="Views/NewsDetail.html" onclick=" doIt(\"' + val.Img + '\"); ">'
```

Comment: I am talking about the <a> tag. The <img> tag is working fine. Thanx for helping though.

Comment: Oh! corrected to anchor tag. As you know in JS both ' and " are same. Just use the other-quote to escape instead of \quote-char. Code looks clean and easy to track string concat issues.

Comment: Sorry, in this case we have to escape the double quote as we have already used both the quotes. so any string inside onclick= "  ........ " has to be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option:

```
   var doItAndRedirect=function(val){
           //do stuff with val here
       window.location = "Views/NewsDetail.html"; 
    }

    jQuery.each(data, function (i, val) {
        var card = '<a href="javascript:doItAndRedirect(\''+ val +'\')">'+
                    '<div class=" card">' +
                    '<img src='+ val.Img + ' />' +
                    '<p>'+ val.Title + '</p>' +
                    '</div>'+
                     '</a>';
        document.getElementById('News').innerHTML += card;
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

It is already a string it just doesn't display `''` on `alert` but at the background it is string only.

Comment: @MurtazaMunshi but you said in your question that function getting called as doIt(abcd);

Answer (score -1):

doIt("' + val.Img + '");

should do it, but if you have, e.g, " inside val.Img you need to quote those: [How do I add slashes to a string in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195568/how-do-i-add-slashes-to-a-string-in-javascript)