# How do I unescape backslash escaped characters?

Tags: javascript, escaping

How can I unescape a string like this in JavaScript

```
alert(\"Testing\");\nconsole.log(\"Hello\");
```

so that is is escaped to this:

```js
alert("Testing");
console.log("Hello");
```

I have a program which uses an api and returns the escaped string, but I want to replace the escaped version of the string with the literal representation, e.g. "\n" with a newline. I saw a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2195568/how-do-i-add-slashes-to-a-string-in-javascript), which had this code to *escape* a string, but it did not say how to undo the operation, to better understand how the string is escaped here is the function in question which *escapes* a string:

```js
function addslashes(string) {
    return string.replace(/\\/g, '\\\\').
        replace(/\u0008/g, '\\b').
        replace(/\t/g, '\\t').
        replace(/\n/g, '\\n').
        replace(/\f/g, '\\f').
        replace(/\r/g, '\\r').
        replace(/'/g, '\\\'').
        replace(/"/g, '\\"');
}
```

I pretty much want to undo that. Thanks in advance!

## Edit

Turns out I can do something like this:

```js
var string = "<!DOCTYPE html><script>alert(\"Hello\");<\/html>"
console.log(unescape(escape(string)));
```

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Have you tried directly displaying the string?

Comment: In my specific case I am making a bookmarklet that beautifies the selected code in any textarea. My API that I made returns an escaped string that I need to unescape.

Answer (score 0):

There's a built in [unescape()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unescape.asp) function you can use

```js
const unescaped = unescape(`alert(\"Testing\");\nconsole.log(\"Hello\");`);
console.log(unescaped)
```

Here's an alternative answer that undoes the specific encoding you did

```js
const escapedString = `alert(\"Testing\");\nconsole.log(\"Hello\");`

function removeSlashes(string) {
    return string.replace('\\\\', /\\/g).
        replace('\\b', /\u0008/g).
        replace('\\t', /\t/g).
        replace('\\n', /\n/g).
        replace('\\f', /\f/g).
        replace('\\r', /\r/g).
        replace('\\\'', /'/g).
        replace('\\"', /"/g);
}

console.log(removeSlashes(escapedString));
```

Comment: I also need it to allow something like "%20" though, without escaping it.

Comment: `unescape` is deprecated.